# SQL querying for multiple COUNT's leads to same (but incorrect) values

Tags: sql, count

I have a dataset, myTable, that looks like this:

```
username   saveType

Alice      auto
Alice      auto
Alice      manual
Alice      manual
Bob        auto
Bob        auto
Bob        auto
Bob        auto
```

I want to count how many auto and manual saveType's were found per user.
Ideally I'd like the query result to look like this:

```
username  AutoCount  ManualCount
Alice     2          2
Bob       4          0
```

But when I run this query:

```
SELECT username, COUNT(saveType="auto") AutoCount, COUNT(savetype="manual") ManualCount
FROM myTable
GROUP BY username
```

I get this instead:

```
username  AutoCount  ManualCount
Alice     4          4
Bob       4          4
```

The db is [data world](https://data.world/). Any explanation for what's going on here would be helpful! Thanks!

Comment: What database is this? SQL Server/MySQL/Postgres? Please tag the db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below using `CASE WHEN`

```
SELECT 
  username, 
  COUNT(case when saveType='auto' then 1 end) AutoCount, 
  COUNT(case when savetype='manual' then 1 end) ManualCount
FROM myTable
GROUP BY username
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, for count it will return null that's why coalesce is used for converting null to 0 :)

Comment: Seems to work fine without `COALESCE`, [see here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eb0b59660c34d13e17e291a2b657b949).  `COUNT` ignores `NULL` values.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, thank you - it's a new learning I didn't know

Comment: The `coalesce()` is redundant.  `count()` never returns `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `COUNT` with `SUM` in your current query and it should work:

```
SELECT
    username,
    SUM(saveType='auto')   AutoCount,
    SUM(savetype='manual') ManualCount
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY username;
```

### Demo

The problem with `COUNT(saveType='auto')` is that the expression inside will either evaluate to 0 (false) or 1 (true).  But, in both cases `COUNT` will count 1 for them.  `SUM` gets around this by effectively ignoring zero values.

Comment: it reaches an error saying that: "Parameter 1 of sum: type 'boolean' detected, 'decimal' expected: (line 3, column 9)"

Comment: I see your output in the demo is correct, it might just be an issue with my DB then possibly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try also this query :

```
select r.username, t1.AutoCount, t2.Manualcount from 
yourtable r inner join (select username,  count(saveType) autoCount from yourtable where saveType='auto' group by username) t1
on t1.username = r.username
inner join  (select username,  count(saveType) ManualCount from yourtable where saveType ='manual' group by username) t2
on t2.username = r.username
```

Hope this can help you.